# Page zooming out on iPad/Mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background, background-image

Ehy there! Can anyone advise how to get the background image totally responsive regardless which device is on? 
Or if the screen is on portrait mode or landscape?

Right now the image I have it covers well the iPad page when is in landscape mode, but is way too short when the screen goes on portrait mode.

This is what i came up with after having tried everything including height: auto; width: auto;

```
#home {
  background-image: url('london-pic.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 720px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined min-height: 720px for some container, so this container won't be higher than 720px. To cover whole screen you should define e.g:

max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;

or

min-height: 100vh.

(use % if parent container have defined height, in other way use vh).

Comment: Piotr I tried - the image gets cut in half like that.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?